# How to build communication between NFC and JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, nfc

I develop a JSF Primefaces application and want to build a communication with NFC Reader.
The NFC Reader is an ACR122U on local PC.
How to solve this situation?

What I know, JSF cannot direct communicate with NFC Reader because web browser don't have the right protocol to direct communication with NFC Reader on local PC.
I tried use Applet, but somehow it is not working. (may be the Java Applet is not supported by modern web browser?)

Is there any way to combine this technology so that they can communicate each others?

My idea, I want to develop a Java desktop application (swing) for NFC. Through this desktop application, JSF can send and receive data from/to desktop application. But I don't know with which technique I can achieve this target (communication between JSF and NFC)?

(no database access from the desktop application)

JSF Web Application <---Data---> Desktop Application

Or may be, anyone has other ideas with tutorial or example to solve this situation?

Thank you...

Comment: A JSF web aplication is precisely that, a web application. So it is not related to JSF and it makes the question more generic.PrimeFaces is a ui component framework on top of JSF so it is not related to that either. NFC is a specific thing you want to access client side, so if you look at that in a broader way, it could be a chipcard reader as well, or a iris scan thing or... So that makes the question even more generic: "How can I have a web server communicate with a client side desktop without the use of a browser"... Start investigating that

Comment: Effectively any client-server protocol will work, like rest.... but if it needs to be two way, websockets come to mind too, but maybe you can have the user start a local 'web page' that can access the reader too... All not related to java, jsf primefaces and nfc)